# How to plot the max value of a coordinate using ListDensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot  y×x from a list with 3 levels using ListDensityPlot. Each sublevel of the list have coordinates of the type
`{{x,y,z1}, {x,y,z2}, {x,y,z3}, {x,y,z4}}`

I would like to represent z1(x,y) → red color, z2(x,y) → blue, z3(x,y) → green, and z4(x,y) → orange.
At each point (x,y), if `z1(x,y)` has the highest value in relation to `z2(x,y)`, `z3(x,y)` and/or `z4(x,y)`, to color the respective point with red color. If at some point (x,y), `z2(x,y)` has the largest value in relation to `z1(x,y)`, `z3(x,y)`, and `z4(x,y)` to color that point with blue. If at any point (x,y), `z3(x,y)` has a value greater than `z1(x,y)`, `z2(x,y)` and/or `z4(x,y)`, then to color the respective point with green. Finally, if at any point (x,y), `z4(x,y)` has a value greater than `z1(x,y)`, `z2(x,y)`, and/or `z3(x,y)`, then to color the respective point with orange. The figure below shows the expected scheme. [image]

`data={{{1, 1, 1057847917}, {1, 1, 1058623892}, {1, 1, 1074383916}, {1, 1, 1010441690}}, {{1, 2, 1044027491}, {1, 2, 1075424963}, {1, 2, 1057484463}, {1, 2, 1024094048}}, {{1, 3, 1029187844}, {1, 3, 1078261789}, {1, 3, 1040954225}, {1, 3, 1036130391}}, {{1, 4, 1013873639}, {1, 4, 1078590140}, {1, 4, 1024684033}, {1, 4, 1048582121}},  {{100, 98, 1077712544}, {100, 98, 1009779118}, {100, 98, 1057483481}, {100, 98, 964942056}}, {{100, 99, 1069779590}, {100, 99, 1025926966}, {100, 99, 1072815469}, {100, 99, 979036982}}, {{100, 100, 1074955040}, {100, 100, 1042207464}, {100, 100, 1063887265}, {100, 100, 993210061}};`

`ListContourPlot[Ordering[data[[All]], -1], PlotPoints -> 50, ContourShading -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}]`

can anybody help me?

Comment: SAC, please revisit [your previous 27 questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/30415/sac?tab=questions) and consider if any answers are worth accepting.

Answer (score 3):

There's already a nice answer from Daniel Huber that uses points, so I'm going to suggest a `MatrixPlot`. This has the advantage of not leaving any gaps between points, but I'm not sure if using points was a requirement or just a suggestion so it may not be exactly what you're looking for.

```
t = Flatten[TakeLargestBy[# -> {"Element", "Index"}, #[[3]] &, 1] & /@ data, 1]
s = SparseArray[{#[[1, 2]], #[[1, 1]]} -> #[[2]] & /@ t]
MatrixPlot[
  s,
  ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Blue, 3 -> Green, 4 -> Orange},
  DataReversed -> True
]
```

[image: MatrixPlot of the data.]

Basically, I'm attaching the position of the largest to the actual data point, then extracting the position and "colour number" and making a `SparseArray`. If your final dataset has no gaps, then it's probably not necessary to use `SparseArray`, you could just create a 100 x 100 matrix of the colour numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, because the resulting imager looks rather queer. Your data has only points in the first and 100th column. Is this correct? Or did you leave out the rest of the data? The picture is therefore rather empty:

```
col[n_] := Switch[n, 1, Red, 2, Blue, 3, Green, 4, Orange];
max = OrderingBy[#, #[[3]] &, -1] & /@ data // Flatten;
cols = col /@ max;
coor = data[[All, 1, 1 ;; 2]];
pts = MapThread[{ #1, Point@#2} &, {cols, coor}];
Graphics[{pts}]
```

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Construct from `data` a matrix  with dimensions `{101, 101}`:

```
dims = 1 +  Max /@ Transpose[Join @@ data[[All, All, ;; 2]]];

sa = SparseArray[data[[All, 1, {2, 1}]] -> 
   (First @ Ordering[#, -1] & /@ data[[All, All, 3]]), dims]
```

Pad your color list with `White` and define a custom color function using [`Blend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html):

```
m = 1 + Max[Length /@ data[[All, All, -1]]];

colors = {Red, Blue, Green, Orange};

cF = Blend[Thread[{Range[0, m], Join[{White}, colors, {White}]}], #] &;
```

Use `cF` as `ColorFunction` in `ListDensityPlot` with the options `InterpolationOrder -> 0` and `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
ListDensityPlot[sa, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> cF,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]